# XML-парсер в CodeIgniter

Tags: xml, php, парсер, codeigniter

Хочу сделать модуль для системы на CodeIgniter, для вывода курса валют. 
Данные хочу парсить с XML-файла отсюда: http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Можно-ли это сделать стандартной библиотекой [xmlrpc](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html)?
Ещё есть вариант, описанный [здесь](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/03/parsing-xml-file-using-codeigniters-simplexml-library/)
Что лучше использовать:? Если использовать первый вариант, приведите пожалуйста пример кода, ибо из их мануала по моей проблеме я ничего не понял. А попытки не привели ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents("filename.xml");

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

foreach($xml->offers->offer as $k=>$val){

/* твои действия */
echo $val -> url; // выведет http://

}
```

подразумевается, что парсим файл типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
 <offers>
  <offer>
   <url>http://...</url>
   <price>150</price>
  </offer>
  <offer>
   <url>http://...</url>
   <price>150</price>
  </offer> 
</offers>
```

итд ...

Comment: Спасибо за более менее понятный пример!
Но в моём файле так вид:
<Cube currency="USD" rate="1.4453"/>
<Cube currency="JPY" rate="116.25"/>
<Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
И я вот не знаю как получить значения.
а при file_get_contents он получает уже готовую страницу, сформированную сервером, ладно, поищу другой способ.